# How can I implement a countdown timer in an ASP.NET page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to show a countdown timer on the top right corner of my ASP page. It should start from 00:00:30 and decrement it to 00:00:00. Then it again start from 30 sec.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

That's a job for javascript.  Just put some html like this on the page:

```
<span id="CountdownTime"></span>
```

And use javascript's setTimeout() and getElementById() functions along with the span's innerHTML property.  Since this is kind of basic I'll leave the actual code as an exercise for the reader.